# Print the values on server side in Laravel Php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-3

I am totally new to PHP and Laravel Framework.I want to print the variables in Laravel on server side to check what values they contains. How can I do `console.log` or print the variable values on the server to see what those contains in Laravel PHP.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Shift Exchange's answer will show you the details on the page, but if you wish to *log* these variables without stopping the processing of the request, you should use the inbuilt `Log` class:

You can [log at various "levels"](http://laravel.com/docs/errors#logging) and when combined with PHP's [`print_r()`](http://www.php.net/print_r) function inspect all manner of variables and arrays in a human-readable fashion:

```
// log one variable at "info" logging level:
Log::info("Logging one variable: " . $variable);

// log an array - don't forget to pass 'true' to print_r():
Log::info("Logging an array: " . print_r($array, true));
```

The `.` above between the strings is important, and used to join the strings together into one argument.

By default these will be logged to the file here:

```
/app/storage/log/laravel.log
```

Comment: Thanx, It is working. I was thinking it also prints the log or data on terminal as itis done in some other frameworks like Django

Comment: @Sajid, great!  You always can use Unix commands such as `tail` or `less` to monitor the log file in the terminal..

Answer (score 6):

The most helpful debugging tool in Laravel is `dd()`. It is a 'print and die' statement

```
 $x = 5;
 dd($x);
 // gives output "int 5"
```

What is cool is that you can place as many variables in `dd()` as you like before dying:

```
 $x = 5;
 $y = 10;
 $z = array(4,6,6);
 dd($x, $y, $z);
```

gives output

```
 int 5
 int 10
 array (size=3) 
     0 => int 4
     1 => int 6  
     2 => int 6
```

Comment: While I agree perfectly with you, isn't OP asking for the [logging](http://laravel.com/docs/errors#logging) commands?

Comment: I think he is asking for both (he also said 'print the variable'). And since he is "totally new to PHP and Laravel" - I'm just keeping it simple.

Comment: yes, I am totally new to PHP, so want to see whatever i am sending in request from browser. and both the ways are equally accepted